# How to pass variables between 2 different files and manipulate them

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, provider

I am learning flutter, and I would like to know how to pass a variable or a method between 2 different files (to add additional widgets).
In my example, I took the code provided by flutter when we create a new project, to this code, I added a second file called "second.dart" in which I get the variable "_counter" in the file main "main.dart" which I multiply by 10.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'second.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int _counter = 0;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Container(
              child: Second(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

second.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class Second extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondState createState() => _SecondState();
}

class _SecondState extends State<Second> {
  
  int counter10 = _MyHomePageState._counter * 10;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: 200,
      height: 300,
      child: Text('My increment * 10 : $counter10 '),
    );
  }
}
```

however, I have this error."_MyHomePageState" is highlighted in red.

> lib/second.dart:11:18: Error: Getter not found: '_MyHomePageState'.
> var counter10 =_MyHomePageState._counter * 10;

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this isn't the way how we pass variables to the other files or other widgets. To create a widget you need to choose between stateful or stateless if you want to manipulate state  from inside of the `Second class` declare it as a stateful but in your case you need to have a stateless widget.

For Example this:

```
    class Second extends StatelessWidget {
      final int counter;
    
      const Second({Key key, this.counter}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return  Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: 200,
      height: 300,
      child: Text('My increment * 10 : ${counter * 10} '));
      }
    }
```

And Pass this variable from your first that is like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'second.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int _counter = 0;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Container(
              child: Second(counter:_counter),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**Note : You can share normal variables by referring them across classes but they shouldn't be private eg have an `_` in front of them. Another thing even if you share your variable it wont have any effect on the Second Page directly as flutter doesn't know that it is changing and rather just treat it as an instance.**

You can share static data using classes:
example

```
class AppStrings {
static Color appColor = Colors.blue;
}
```

And later refer to it as AppStrings.appColor

Comment: Thank you for your help Krish your code worke fine , but is it possible to let the calcul part (_counter * 10 ) only in the second.dart file ?

Comment: @igachi I have updated my code. And Your query is answered

Comment: i have a question about the constructor , what is the difference between that `const Second({Key key, this.counter}) : super(key: key);` and that `const Second(this.counter);`

Answer (score 1):

There are some points that you should do in your codes:

1. when we use underscore as the first character of the variable name, it means that this variable is private! so you can not use `int counter10 = _MyHomePageState._counter * 10;` in the second widget!
2. if you want to pass variables to the child widget, you need to create a constructor as follow:

```
    class Second extends StatefulWidget {
    
      int counter;
    
      Second(this.counter);
      @override
      _SecondState createState() => _SecondState();
    }
```

3. now you can pass _countre variable to the Second widget:

```
    Container(
                  child: Second(_counter),
                ),
```

please let me know if there is any problem or error.

Comment: Thank you Hasan for your help , do I replace this `int counter10 = _MyHomePageState._counter * 10;` with this `int counter10 = Second.counter * 10; ` (but issu ,counter is highlighted)

Comment: If you want to use a constructor, you should actually use ```int counter10 = widget.counter *10```. But note that you should do it in the method or initState method.

Comment: Thx ! , I used a method like this  `int counter10;
  int incrementCounter10() {
    return counter10 = widget.counter * 10;` and it's ok , but you talk about the initState method , I didn't really understand the difference between a simply method or a initState method ?

Comment: Great! for more information please check this link https://medium.com/dscreva/initstate-and-didchangedependencies-methods-in-flutter-explained-37e043e35c79